# When do you give in-game advice?

Tags: game-design, user-experience, psychology

I'm interested in the process of automatically generating advice when a player is consistently struggling through parts of a game.  Suppose I already know what advice I want to generate (e.g., "Press A twice to double-jump across long gaps").  My question is twofold:

1. Has it been shown that this intervention can be useful to gamer experience?
2. Has it been shown that excessive intervention will be ignored or will cause frustration?

References to game design or psychology research papers is a plus!

Comment: A piece of in-game advice is typically called _a hint_. :) You might want to revise the question and title so that it includes this keyword.

Comment: Have a look at this question which I think is incredibly similar: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66466/tutorial-text-without-annoying-user

Comment: On the tech side you could plot player reaction v time to decide the median time to hint.  Don't ask a focus group, because focus groups don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any social studies about this. But good rule for happy player is do not force them to do what they dont want to. 
As for tutorial type help, many games have a checkbox "stop showing tutorial tips" or something similar on the popup window, and option in game menu to re-enable it later. In Trine there was also an option to show puzzle hints after x minutes stuck on the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I like exploring what the controls are without the game taking me by the hand for the first twenty minutes. Take your average (gamer) person and put them in front of a computer to play your game. Do they get stuck somewhere because of a lack of knowledge concerning controls? Then place a hint regarding that there.